# Reusable function to adjust the width of combobox items to longest item in the list

Tags: vb.net, combobox

My intent is to be able to use a function to adjust the width of the drop down so that all items included in the drop down are shown (length wise). I'm trying to create a function where I'll be able to use it for multiple comboboxes. Currently this is being called from a LOAD CBO function, after the data has been loaded however it is not adjusting the .dropDownWidth.

```
Private Sub AdjustCombobox(ByVal comboboxName As ComboBox)
    Dim maxwidth = 0
    Dim temp = 0

    For Each Item As Object In comboboxName.Items
        temp = TextRenderer.MeasureText(Item.ToString(), comboboxName.Font).Width
        If temp > maxwidth Then
            maxwidth = temp
        End If
    Next

    comboboxName.DropDownWidth = maxwidth
End Sub
```

EDIT:

comboboxload function

```
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(sql, objconnection)
        Dim ds As New DataSet

        da.Fill(ds, "Prov")

        If ds.Tables("Prov").Rows.Count > 0 Then
            With c
                .DataSource = ds.Tables("Prov")
                .ValueMember = "No"
                .DisplayMember = "Name"
                .SelectedIndex = -1
            End With
        End If
```

Comment: The width of the dropdown is independent: are you looking for `.DropDownWidth`?

Comment: Yes I just figured this one out - sorry @plutonix - updated the question

Comment: Also, please quit putting lang tags in your titles

Comment: I dont quite follow the new version.  The selected item isnt a graphics issue.

Comment: When I click on the drop down - the items are all displayed with the correct length - however since there is about 30 of them in it - the scroll is all the way at the bottom - showing the last few items - instead of being on the top showing the first few items

Comment: Thats not the normal CBO behavior - they dont automatically scroll to the bottom unless one at the bottom is the selected item.  Sounds like there might be code somewhere causing it

Comment: @plutonix - it's a cleared combobox on load i set it to .selectedIndex=-1 and this is when i click on drop down. Automatically defaults to it

Comment: Hard to tell with the redaction, but the blue indicates there **is** something selected and that item happens to be at the bottom of the list.

Comment: @plutonix I just set it to .selectedIndex=0. I hope you don't mind me asking without starting a new question but is there a way to have this function handle multiple comboboxes. I'm currently doing it on dropdown EVENT - i am specifying in the function which combobox it is to affect

Comment: Yes, just pass the cbo as a param...but `MeasureString` probably isnt the correct way to measure.  I'm pretty sure the ComboBoxRenderer uses the TextRenderer, and there is no reason to loop thru items, just measure the longest text (plus a fudge factor) ...and do dont it in the DropDown/opened whatever event - it only has to be done once

Comment: Yes, TextRender works well - just 3 lines of code too

Comment: @plutonix - this is what I came up with - not much really happens - I call this fnction once the combobox gets loaded

Comment: Please fix the post to omit the issues relating to SelectedItem or just post a new question.  These are not supposed to meander from topic to topic like this

Comment: How are the cbos populated?  Are you adding items or binding to a datasource?  If a DS what is it? DataTable, List(T)?  It matters for a generic helper

Comment: @plutonix binding using dataset please see edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would use the actual `DataSource`, not the items.  This allows a really short solution:

```
Private Function GetMaxDataSize(dt As DataTable, mem As String) As Int32

    Dim longestItem = dt.AsEnumerable.Select(Function(q) q.Field(Of String)(mem)).
                OrderBy(Function(z) z.Length).
                Last()

    ' assumes as the CBO's use the same Font
    Dim longestSize = TextRenderer.MeasureText(longestItem, cboE.Font)
    Return longestSize.Width +
                SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth + 5

End Function
```

Note that the method accounts for the `VerticalScrollBarWidth` and a slight fudge factor to account for internal gutters, padding, margins etc.  If different combos use different fonts, pass each to the method as well.  Usage:

```
' "Text" is the DisplayMember name / column name
cboE.DropDownWidth = GetMaxDataSize(dtLorem, "Text")
```

Using "Lorem ipsum dolor" fragments, with one especially long one, the result:

[image]

Comment: @this seems to work great with DataTable - however it doesn't work with Dataset :/

Comment: A DataSet contains no data - it is a DataTable holder.  pass `myDS.Tables("Lorem")`

Comment: it says asEnumerable in not member of systems.data.dataTable - i have imports.system.data

Comment: If it works with a "naked" DataTable, it will work with a DataTable held by a DataSet.  All you do is ***pass*** the DT:  `Dim ThisSize = GetMaxDataSize(myDataSet.Tables("TABLE_NAME"), "COL_NAME")`  no need to change the method, just how you invoke it